# though it is repeated question but how can i display new row in the first row i am using angular9

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, angular9, ag-grid-angular

I am able to add a new row but it is getting on the last page at the and. I want to display in the first row. Can anyone help me out with this?
HTML component

```
  <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="addRow()">
            <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
            <span>Add</span></button>
```

ts code

```
 addRow(){
         this.agGrid.api.applyTransaction({
           add: [{make: '', model: '', price: ''}]
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `updateRowData` method on the grid Api, which allows you to specify an index which to insert at. Change your `addRow` method to this:

```
addRow() {
    let newRows = [{ make: "", model: "", price: '' }];
    this.gridApi.updateRowData({ add: newRows, addIndex: 0 });
  }
```

Take a look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-1rjvgs) StackBlitz.

Comment: still rows are getting displayed at last

Comment: take a look at the stackblitz, the new row is added to the beginning.

Comment: i went through stackbltz and also copy paste HTML and TS . but still rows are getting displayed at last

Comment: provide a full StackBlitz or Plunker of your code that is not working. Also take a look at [this](https://embed.plnkr.co/3f7JBrRSvVEWAuxQ7PuP/) comprehensive example from ag-Grid.

Comment: unless you reproduce a full example, I can't help. [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-yubqgv) is the stackblitz of your html which is working.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dyaf6y . some modules need to be imported. Please check the code .

Comment: I tried with your above code. result is same. rows are getting added at last

Comment: take a look at [this](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-immutable-data/#example-immutable-store)

Comment: Please take a look into this and help me out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63069026/ag-grid-is-not-getting-refresh-after-adding-a-new-row-i-am-using-angular-9.