# Ag grid is not getting refresh after adding a new row. I am using angular 9

Tags: typescript, grid, ag-grid, angular9

I am using angular 9 .
I want to add a new row dynamically on clicking add button and refresh the data with including a new data on clicking update button.
example :
[On clicking add button, user can enter the data.[but on clicking on update button, table should get refresh with the new data and maintain its structure.]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aqxk.png)..
I have went through all the possibilities , but it is not helping me out. I am able to refresh the row with the default data in the code but not able to refresh the row with the dynamic values.

TS code.

```
gridApi : any;
   columnApi: any;
   
   
  
    @ViewChild('agGrid') agGrid: AgGridAngular;
    title = 'app';

    columnDefs = [
        {headerName: 'Make', field: 'make', sortable: true, filter: true, checkboxSelection: true,editable: true }
        {headerName: 'Model', field: 'model', sortable: true, filter: true, editable: true },
        {headerName: 'Price', field: 'price', sortable: true, filter: true, editable: true}
    ];

    rowData: any;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
 
      this.rowData = this.http.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/master/grid-packages/ag-grid-docs/src/sample-data/rowData.json')
      }
   save(){
     console.log('Save', this.rowData);
   }
  
  addRow() {
    let newRows = [{  make: "", model: "", price: '' }];
    this.agGrid.api.updateRowData({ add: newRows});
    this.agGrid.api.setPinnedTopRowData(newRows);
    
    }
    
  
  onGridReady(params) {
    this.agGrid.api = params.api;
    this.columnApi = params.columnApi;
    
  }

   updateRow(){
    
      
      this.gridApi.setRowData(this.rowData); // Refresh grid
      console.log(this.rowData);
    }
  
  gridOptions = {
  }
```

HTML code.

```
<ag-grid-angular 
    #agGrid
    style="width: 500px; height: 450px"
    class="ag-theme-alpine"
    [rowData]="rowData | async"
   (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
   [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
   
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    rowSelection="multiple"
    [animateRows]= "true"
    [pagination]="true"
    >
</ag-grid-angular>
```

Comment: I've created a StackBlitz of your issue [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-3ufylq) but don't quite understand what you're trying to achieve. Please update your question with what you're trying to achieve as opposed to _not able to refresh the row with the dynamic values_.

Comment: as you can see , on adding a row, new empty row is generated in the first row  where the user is entering the details and row is getting added successfully in the last row. but on clicking an update button , the new row where the user is able to enter the details (i.e first row) should be removed and table should get refreshed with the original structure including the new data.

Comment: you've got the new row pinned to the top. Also, rowData is not a 2 way binding, i.e. adding a new row won't updated `rowData`. Take a look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-xfsk9u) and see if it helps.

Comment: no , it didn't work . with the code mentioned by you original table is also not getting generated now. while debugging . it is throwing an error as :  Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]